# Frame Rate Jitter Issue when Relaying Video Tracks with Chrome WebRTC

Tags: webrtc

#### Frame Rate Jitter When Publishing a 1280 x 720 Video Track after Subscribing within a Local Network in WebRTC

I initially subscribe to a video track within a local network, and the video track has a resolution of 1280 x 720. The subscription parameters include a maximum bitrate of 3 Mbps, and degradationPreference is set to "maintain-resolution." During this phase, I observe that the video track's resolution remains stable, and the frame rate is consistently 25 frames per second (FPS).

However, when I subsequently publish this same video track to a remote destination with publishing parameters set to a maximum bitrate of 3 Mbps and degradationPreference set to "maintain-resolution," I encounter frame rate jitter in both the previously subscribed local network stream and the current published stream.

I suspect that this issue might be caused by a variety of factors, such as WebRTC configuration, network conditions, or possibly encoding and transmission settings. I've attempted to optimize some of these factors, but the problem persists.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights on how to diagnose and resolve this frame rate jitter issue, especially when transitioning from local network subscription to remote publishing.

Thank you for your assistance!